# Visual Studio installation problems

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

[image]I have a problem with visual studio. Whenever I try to install it I get the following errors:

Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2999226)
The data is invalid

Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23918
User cancelled installation

How can I fix this? I have already tried installing the Windows (KB2999226) update manualy, but it always fails.

Just to mention, I do have legal MS Windows 8.1
Here is a link to the log file:
http://www.filedropper.com/log_5

Comment: better to provide screenshot and logfile.

Comment: Did it! Thank you for telling me that!